# Equivalent code to replace pixels in Java OpenCV

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I am currently doing an android application with OpenCV where Java is used to process image segmentation. I need to replace the pixel from labels to rgb_image. Is there any equivalent code in Java to perform the similar task as the c++ code below?

```
    cv::Mat rgb_image(height, width, CV_8UC3);
    cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> rgb_first = rgb_image.begin<cv::Vec3b>();
    cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> rgb_last = rgb_image.end<cv::Vec3b>();
    cv::MatConstIterator_<int> label_first = labels.begin<int>();

    cv::Mat centers_u8;
    centers.convertTo(centers_u8, CV_8UC1, 255.0);
    cv::Mat centers_u8c3 = centers_u8.reshape(3);

    while ( rgb_first != rgb_last ) {
            const cv::Vec3b& rgb = centers_u8c3.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(*label_first)[0];
            *rgb_first = rgb;
            ++rgb_first;
            ++label_first;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to use Mat.get() method to get pixel values. like:

```
        byte[] vec3=new byte[3];

    for(int i=0;i<src.cols();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<src.rows();j++)
        {
            src.get(j, i, vec3);
        }
    }
```

anyone knows how to use iterator ways? I am not familiar with that.